# Compile time creation of unordered_map (hashtable) also extended by classes at compile time

Tags: c++, hashtable, unordered-map, compile-time

Hello I have the following situation.

I'm using c++14, and I have several classes whose objects are serialized via JSON objects.  In order to determine the class of the object the JSON file represents, the JSON has a `className` field, which maps to a string of the classname for example:

```
{
    ...,
    className: "class_one",
    ...,
}
```

Instead of comparing each string to each available class I would like to do use a hash-table, `std::unordered_map`.  The problem is I would need to manually create a hash-table that has all the class mapping of strings to the proper initialization functions for each class (all the classes inherit from the same super class here).  I would like to instead do a compile time creation of this table and add new entries based on each new class that inherits from the super class I mentioned earlier. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds feasible. Check out [`CompileTimeArmor::StaticHashMap`](https://github.com/ChoppinBlockParty/CompileTimeArmor).